# Symfony2 Validation Reverted Not Working

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I had added below validation in validation.yml of my bundle

```
Acme\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Makes:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        status:
            - NotBlank: ~            
        type:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

But later i needed to remove `NotBlank` validation for `status` field so i removed that line and my current code is:

```
Acme\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Makes:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        type:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

Now, still the the validation for status field is being checked in the form on submit even after clearing cache.

Any suggestion?

Comment: do you use something like apc or opcode cache? it's possible that the old state is still being cached in there because cached files/classes are not being invalidated if the corresponding files change with production settings.

Comment: I don't use any additional caching mechanism besides inbuilt caching of symfony2. Yes i am running production instance so in this case how to come out of this issue?

Comment: restart php-fpm if you're using it - otherwise try to restart your apache service. developing with production settings sounds kind of wrong to me btw... aehm and you are not mixing up browser validation and symfony's validation, right? i mean ... you do submit the form with a request visible in your firebug/devtools network tab and get a validation error from symfony ... and not just your browser using html5-validation and telling you the field was required?

Answer (score 1):

Check your the mapping of your field "status" in the Makes entity has parameter `nullable=true`, if not, the field will automatically required in forms.

Comment: I used novalidate and also placed server side validation in.. so now its working .

Comment: If "status" field is not nullable, an doctrine error will be thrown when you'll flush after fill a form with status=null.